# How can you display a stub page when an MVC app starts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8

I would like to display a splash startup page when my MVC app is loading.  While this was answered in [Displaying a stub page while ASP.NET app starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335925/displaying-a-stub-page-while-asp-net-app-starts) I can't figure out how to make this work for MVC.

The basics for a regular webforms app is adding something like the following to web.config

```
<applicationInitialization
    remapManagedRequestsTo="Startup.htm" 
    skipManagedModules="true" >
  <add initializationPage="/default.aspx" />
</applicationInitialization>
```

The problem I can't figure out is how to set the initializationPage for the home controller.  I'm using IIS8.