# Application_Start won't fire when inheriting Global.asax from a vendor's Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to add code to the application_start event of a 3rd party ASP.NET web application for which I don't have the source code. I'm doing this by inheriting from the vendor's Global class. Here's the code (note "new" keyword and the two calls to the base class versions of the events. This is because the base class methods aren't abstract, virtual or overrides and I don't have the source code to change that):

```
public class CustomGlobal : VendorNamespace.Global
{
    new protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var logName = "SPPCustom";
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(logName))
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(logName, "Application");
        var text = "Hello from Application Start!";
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(logName, "Application started!");
        File.WriteAllText(@"c:\ApplicationStart.txt", text);
        Debug.WriteLine(text);
        base.Application_Start(sender, e);
    }
    new protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var logName = "SPPCustom";
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(logName))
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(logName, "Application");
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(logName, "Session started!");
        base.Session_Start(sender, e);
    }
}
```

I'm referencing my code in the global.asax file for the site like so:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MyNamespace.CustomGlobal" Language="C#" %>
```

The Application_Start code doesn't execute but the Session_Start code does. I can write events and write out text files from Session_Start but Application_Start, nadda.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Edit:

Here's the code now after implementing Jan's suggestion:
public class CustomGlobal : HttpApplication
    {
        private readonly Global _global;
        private readonly MethodInfo _appStartInfo;
        private readonly MethodInfo _sessionStartInfo;

```
    public CustomGlobal()
    {
        _global = new Global();
        _appStartInfo = typeof(Global).GetMethod("Application_Start", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        _sessionStartInfo = typeof(Global).GetMethod("Session_Start", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var logName = "SPPCustom";
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(logName))
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(logName, "Application");
        var text = "Hello Patient Portal from Application Start!";
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(logName, "Application started!");
        File.WriteAllText(@"c:\PatientPortalApplicationStart.txt", text);
        Debug.WriteLine(text);
        //_sxaGlobal.ApplicationStart(sender, e);
        _appStartInfo.Invoke(_global, new[] {sender, e});
    }
}
```

Now it throws the following error:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
```

Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +28

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +0
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +72
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +251
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +28
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +19
   CustomGlobal.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +231

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9239341
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +131
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +194
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +339
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +253

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9157968
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext         context) +256

Comment: And one more thing, I am restarting the web site in IIS, making a request for an Asp.net page before checking the event log to see whether Application_Start() executed.

Comment: How are you determining that the Application_Start isn't running, if you just put a breakpoint in it and start debugging it will not be hit because the debugger attaches after the application has started.

Comment: I'm determining it based on the fact that the message isn't written to the event log above. Also, the File.WriteAllText() call doesn't write the file. However, both of these function calls work inside of Session_Start. I have not tried debugging it.

Answer (score 1):

It's inheritance problem. When `new` keyword is used then calling `CustomGlobal.Application_Start()` will execute your code, but calling `((HttpApplication) CustomGlobal).Application_Start()` will execute vendor's code.

Solution could be pattern with private member

```
public class CustomGlobal : HttpApplication
{
    private readonly VendorGlobal _global;
    private readonly MethodInfo _appStartInfo;

    public CustomGlobal()
    {
        _global = new VendorGlobal();
        _appStartInfo = typeof(VendorGlobal).GetMethod("Application_Start", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _appStartInfo.Invoke(_global, new[] {sender, e});
        // your custom code
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the vendor's Application_Start() is "protected" not "public". I cannot call the method in VendorGlobal without inheritance. Why do you think inheritance is the issue with my code to begin with? You'll note that the Session_Start() method in my code works via inheritance (base.SessionStart()) and it also uses "new". Why is Application_Start any different?

Comment: It's hard to say, Application_Start is called by HttpApplicationFactory on HttpApplication object (so VendorGlobal is used), but I was unable to track Session_Start call. Anyway you can always call protected methods via reflection or child class.

Comment: I see your point now, thanks! I've implemented your code. I feel like we are close. Now, though, it throws the following error:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   VendorGlobal.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +28

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo ...CustomGlobal.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e

I could not post the whole thing of course.

Comment: I have just placed the new code and exception that is thrown as an edit above. Thanks!

Comment: Jan, I realize now this was not nearly enough info to solve the above error. Since I last posted, I have decompiled the vendor source code in dotPeak. I have added their Global class to a test project and called Application_Start with Reflection. They have a statement in Application_Start: (this.Application["failureCount"] = (object)0;) where this.Application is null. This must the source of the null reference exception. My question now is why would this.Application be null when calling their dll from MethodInfo.Invoke but while inheriting it works?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do (_global.Application = this.Application;) because Application has no setter. What can I do?

Comment: Now if you have source code, then you can modify it (if the result from dotPeek can be compiled). As this class is called from outside  (referenced in Global.asax) it should work without modifying vendor's assembly.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I could just cut and paste all of their code into my Global.asax.cs, put my assembly into the server installation along with theirs? I believe I could do this but I don't know if that would have any side effects. Their assembly has lots of namespaces besides the one containing Global. I suppose that as long as their original assembly is still present, and only the Global.asax.cs code were placed in my assembly, then Asp.net could initialize the application from my assembly instead of theirs? I'm not sure if this is what you mean but it's the only option I can think  of.

Comment: In other words, I would duplicate their code from Global.asax.cs into my assembly, but in a different namespace. Then, point Asp.net to my via the "Inherits" attribute in the Global.asax markup. Is that my only option that you are aware?

Comment: Global shouldn't contain much code, to make the duplication difficult. But you can run in another problems like using internal memebres or referencing Global from other classes. Check also this [StackOverflow: Hook into Application_Start in a HttpModule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779137/hook-into-application-start-in-a-httpmodule) if it's solution for you instead of overriding Global

Comment: That suggestion looks like just the thing. I'm going to give it a try.